# How to create password for WD MyPassport if drive doesn't show up in WD Smartware Settings tab?

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, passwords

Is it possible to set a password for Western Digital Smartware backups on a WD My Passport Ultra once the backup function has already been used? When I go to the Settings tab, it only shows my computer. I’ve looked through the WD manual and forums and they aren’t any help because they all assume that the drive will show up under the settings tab. How can I set a password without seeing the drive there? 
I am using 64 bit Windows 7.

[image: Drive doesn't show in Settings tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the WD My Passport Ultra model there is a separate utility for setting the password on the HDD. This is why you only have the software settings tab in WD Smartware. You can download WD Security for Windows here: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=LDL8dT